# How to force WebDriver to execute a command while the webpage is not loaded completely?

Tags: java, selenium

Webpage loads from top to bottom.

```
1) <html ...
2) <head ...
3) <body ...
  etc
```

I need my WebDriver explicitly wait until the `<title` tag is visible. Then read the content of the title, and continue doing other actions ***without waiting for the whole page being loaded!!!***.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 0) // This line is probably the one to be transformed in order to correspond to my requirements
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//title")));
// The problem is that the following commands do not start off until the whole page is loaded
if(driver.getTitle().equals("whatever")) {
driver.get("http://");
}
else {
...
}
```

Comment: Webdriver blocks until a webpage completely loads. I'm afraid I don't know of any method to allow you to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Is there any other API that allows this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `pageLoadTimeout`. Set the timeout to `0` and then catch the `TimeoutException` and then do your specific Title asserts etc.

`driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

**UPDATE**

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
try {
    driver.get("http://");
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//title")));
}
```

For more [info](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#pageLoadTimeout%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29)

Ideally you should use `ExpectedConditions.titleIs()`
More info for the available options, can be found [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html).

Comment: Thank You +1. But this is not the explicit wait. pageLoadTimeout set to zero does not allow enough time for the title tag to be uploaded at all. Also, in some cases title tag requires 2 seconds and in some 5 to be uploaded, and that is fine as long as no time is waited on other elements

Comment: Updated my answer, based on your concerns.

Comment: After you catch the page load timeout error, then you need to `wait` for the next expected condition(that being the presence of a title).

Comment: This does not work. Because we have specified `driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` Therefore even after we catch the `TimeoutException`, the `wait.until...` line would throw another `TimeoutException that is not caught by anything

Comment: Why would you want it to be caught, you would want the test to fail if the title element is not present even after 30 seconds.

Comment: Also, in the example above we are checking for `visibilityofElement`, `title` is not visible. If you must check for title, wait for element located rather than visible.

Comment: Updated my answer to wait for `presenceOfElementLocated`, which will wait 30 seconds for the element with xpath `//title` to be present. After which it will fail.